# Access to ENV variables defined in ${workspaceFolder}/.env files

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For a project I need to define the ENVIRO variable (and some others) with the values prod/stage/dev.
This variable is used in .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml, .devcontainer/Dockerfile, some shell scripts and the Python source to set paths and the like.

Therefore I defined the file [${workspaceFolder}/.env which is imported by the Python extension like described here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments):

```
ENVIRO=dev
...
```

To avoid to execute / debug my code in the wrong environment, I wanted to create a little VSC extension, which does nothing else than to show the value of the ENVIRO variable in the Status Bar at the bottom.

Now the problem. In the extensions activate function I don't get access to the ENV variables defined in .env file:

```
const envValue = process.env["ENVIRO"];
// gives: undefined
```

In an terminal in the same VSC instance:

```
echo $ENVIRO
# gives: dev
```

When I access ENV variables defined by the system (not the .env file), there is no problem to access them in the extension's activate function:

```
export function activate( context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const envValue = process.env["NVM_BIN"];
  // gives: '/Users/andi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin'
```

Is there no way to access this variable?

My suspicion is following:

- The Python extension extends the Environment with the variables [using the EnvironmentVariableCollection](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_environment-variable-collection)
- This adds them to the terminal environment, but prevents access to the variables in other extensions.

Or do I (hopefully) miss something?

Comment: you only have access to the environment of the shell that VSC is started from, the Python extension starts a new shell, the extensions have no access to that shell. You can get the content by reading the `.env` file yourself, but that does possibly not reflect the value in the new shell used

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for your confirmation. Reading the file will do for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily show any .env variables with ease.

At first, you can use pytest-dotenv extension, which allows declarations in pytest.ini like follows:

```ini
[pytest]
env_files =
    .env
    .test.env
    .deploy.env
```

At second, all local variable can be set in python script command, like that:

```bash
python -m pytest test\test_envs.py
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env -m python
import os

current_env=os.getenv('ENVIRO','')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(current_env)
```

That will shows you corresponding .env you have in docker or local file system.

At third, you can use my [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hack2root.testfilesonsave) to see the command log, then you provide the command to my extension like this:

```json
    "testFilesOnSave.enabled": true,
    "testFilesOnSave.languageId": "c",
    "testFilesOnSave.testCommands": [
        {
            "python": "python -m ${workspaceFolder}\test\test_envs.py"
        }
    ]
```

And switch to Output for 'Test Files on Save' section and just save some output.

Also it can be run in docker container remotely, i suppose.

If you need just simple code for execution as VSCode extension, this is a code snipped for processing ${env:ENVIRO}:

```js
    const regex = /\${env:(.*?)}/g;
    const matches = commandText.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
        const resolvedString = matches.reduce((acc: string, match: string) => {
            const variableName = match.slice(6, -1);
            const variableValue = process.env[variableName] ?? '';
            return acc.replace(match, variableValue);
        }, commandText);
        commandText = resolvedString;
    }
    console.log(commandText);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answering 3 years later! I can hardly remember, why I needed this back then, but I am sure it helps somebody else.